# jquery mobile single pages open as popup

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm making a mobile website using with JQM v1.4.

I made the pages as each single HTML. Ex) sub1.html, sub2.html, sub3.html

Is this possible to open sub2.html as popup(dialog)  when click something in sub1.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery mobile has the ability to open another page in a popup. Its called Popup iframes.

```
<a href="#popupMap" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">Open Map</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupMap" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" data-corners="false" data-tolerance="15,15">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    <iframe src="sub2.html" width="480" height="320" seamless=""></iframe>
</div>
```

Check the documentation at:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/popup-iframe/
AND
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/popup/

Comment: Also, please avoid using Dialogs as suggested elsewhere. They are deprecated in 1.4 and will be removed in 1.5. See [HERE](http://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this at http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0-rc.2/docs/pages/dialog/index.html using JQM dialog it is possible. Did you checked it?